# import package dynamically

Tags: python, import

I'd like to understand if there's better solution .
for following tree:

```
|-main.py
├── app_config
│   ├── db_config.py
|   |--- settings.py
```

Main.py importing class from db_config

```
from app_config.db_config import DBContext
```

So in db_config.py each import of other class would be in the context/position of main
meaning

```
from app_config.settings import SingletonMeta
```

This obviously works but during development sometimes need to test db_config.py itself
and each time need to change import of settings.py

```
from  settings import SingletonMeta
```

I wonder if there's more efficient way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code in your `db_config.py` script:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
from app_config.settings import <package>
```

This way, you add the parent directory of `db_config.py` to sys and this will alows you to import packages inside your script as `from app_config.settings import <any package under app_config >` and also in `main.py`

Comment: thanks this solved it ,small correction: ```sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))```

Comment: Sorry! I have just updated!